# Django objects.all() return empty queryset

Tags: python, django, sqlite

I have a sqlite3 database that has pre-existing data(name, price, url, img,...). When i tried to print the value from objects.all() it return <QuerySet []> and loop through the list in templates return nothing

My models

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    current_price = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    place = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    url = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    img = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    date_add = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

My urls:

```
path("database", views.show_db, name="show_db")
```

My views:

```
def show_db(request):
    product_list = Product.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'product_list.html', {'product_list' : product_list})
```

My templates:

```
{% block content %}
    {% for product in product_list %}
        <li>
            {{product.name}}
        </li>
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

When i use dbshell to check, there is a scrape_product table(scrape is the name of the app):

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "scrape_product"(
  "id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
  "name" varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  "current_price" varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  "place" varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  "url" varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  "img" varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  "date_add" datetime NOT NULL
);
```

Comment: Can you open the database and give us a screenshot of the pre-existing data?

Comment: hi! it quite long so i save it to gg drive: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1FXvg5986WgmGYS56vujpBLO4Fivo2L1L?usp=sharing

Comment: Is `scrape_product` the name of the pre-existing table? It could be that Django is looking at the wrong table.

Comment: @Gediminas ok i just checked. I connect to the db file and have a sql query like this c.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS products (url TEXT, name TEXT, current_price TEXT, place TEXT, img TEXT, date_add TEXT)"). I just gonna delete the exist one and see if data show up

Comment: after delete my db and save data to it, still return empty queryset when use objects.all()

Comment: Make sure you do not have two tables in your database: one named `scrape_product` and the other `products`. Django will use the name `scrape_product` by its convention.

Comment: when i delete database and migrations and create a new one, open file db.sqlite3 table products show up with all correct data but dbshell still shows only scrape_product

Comment: So my guess is that you either need to rename your `products` table to `scrape_product` or vice versa.

Comment: Perhaps this might also be useful: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/options/#db-table

Comment: oh ok it worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved: rename sqlite table of Product model using

```
class Meta:
  db_table = "scrape_product"
```