# Django how to update price of an item if that item existed or save that item to database if not

Tags: django, sqlite

My models:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    current_price = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    place = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    url = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    img = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    date_add = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    def __str__(self):
         return self.name
```

My codes:

```
def cellphones(query):
    lists = []
    search = query.replace(' ', '%20')
    url = f"https://cellphones.com.vn/catalogsearch/result?q={search}" driver.get(url)
    content = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[id*='search-catalog-page']")
    items = content.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[class*='product-info']")
    for _ in items:
        item = Item(url=_.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a").get_attribute('href'), name=_.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "h3").text, current_price=_.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "p[class*='product__price--show']").text, place="Cellphones", img=_.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "img").get_attribute('src'), date_add=datetime.datetime.now())
        if Product.objects.filter(name=item.name, place=item.place).first():
            t = Product.objects.get(name=item.name, place=item.place)
            t.current_price = item.current_price
            t.img = item.img
            t.date_add = item.date_add
            t.save()
        else:
            save_to_db(item)
        lists.append(item)
    return lists
```

save_to_db:

```
def save_to_db(item):
    conn = sqlite3.connect('../db.sqlite3')
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS products (url TEXT, name TEXT, current_price TEXT, place TEXT, img TEXT, date_add TEXT)")
    c.execute("INSERT INTO products VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", 
    (item.url, item.name, item.current_price, item.place, item.img, item.date_add))
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
```

I want to update the price, date add of an item if that item already exists in the database. If that item not existed, i want to add it to the database.
But the item will always save to the database. I think it the same problem i have here [Django objects.all() return empty queryset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77188859/django-objects-all-return-empty-queryset) where Product object return empty queryset. How do i fix this?

Comment: Have you tried doing so using django orm's `update_or_create` method?

Comment: when using update_or_create i don't need to update or save the item manually right because i don't see anything change in the database when search for the same keyword